# Issues with Open JPA with @Convert and @Converter - field not being recognized

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

I am having a lot of difficulties getting @Convert and @Converter using Open JPA.

`some_field` is a longtext field in the database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "basic")
public class Basic {

    @Column(name = "some_field")
    @Lob
    @Convert(converter = SomeFieldConverter.class)
    private SomeField someField;
...
}

@Converter
public class SomeFieldConverter implements AttributeConverter<SomeField, String> {
...
}
```

However, it seems like JPA is completely ignoring `SomeField`.

Debugging through the code during JPA initialization, in `AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser` when it tries to get a `PersistenceStrategy` from that column, it return null. This is because it's reading `SomeField` as an object, and since it's not an enum object it has no persistence strategy. This causes it not get added to declared fields, and essentially ignored.

I can get past this by marking it as @Basic as that manually assigns a persistence strategy. No examples show this being required. Is there a way to do this without this annotation? Why is this annotation required?

But even when it's recognized I run into the following issue: `CannotCreateTransactionException ... Basic.someField declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "blob".`

I can get around this by marking the field as `longblob` instead of `longtext`, but I'd rather avoid DB changes. Is there a way to make this work keeping it as `longtext`? Or do I have to make it `longblob`? Why is this a requirement for this to work?